# Tautology or not?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I’d be grateful for your help for what, on first glance may appear to be a legal question, but I believe that its essence is an English question.

I was recently involved in a court case where a contract used the phrase "deal must be effected by themselves". The phrase referred to the conditions under which someone would be entitled to a commission.

The judge said that if the clause had said "must be effected by themselves ONLY", it could be accepted that the contracted person had to effect a deal on their own and without the assistance of anyone else to receive a commission, but that without the word “only”, it would refer to any deal done by the person, irrespective of if they did the deal on their own or not.

It has since been contended that the judge's preferred statement represents tautology in English. Does the phrase mean “on their own and without the assistance of anyone else” without the added “only”?

What do you think?

Comment: If this is indeed an English question and not a legal question, then we can only answer about how the phrase sounds to a layperson. However, much legalese doesn't make much sense to a layperson, so, no matter what answers you get here, they won't really have any bearing on your case. If you want to discuss the judge's ruling, that would be more appropriate on [law.se].

Comment: The actual jurisdiction is not given, and - importantly - the law usually depends on legislation and precedent rather than dictionaries and grammar..

Comment: It can be interpreted either way—especially without any greater context. (But I suspect even if one.)